# Commutative diagrams with antiparallel arrows

Tags: category-theory, definition

A diagram in category theory is said to *commute* when for all objects $A$ and $B$ in it, every the composite morphism resulting from a possible path from $A$ to $B$ are the identical. Does that mean that if the following diagram commutes,

[image]

Then $g = h \circ e = h \circ e \circ (f \circ e) = h \circ e \circ (f \circ e)^2 = h \circ e \circ (f \circ e)^3$ and so on?

If so, then commutative diagrams with antiparallel arrows (like $e$ and $f$ in the above diagram) must be heavily restricted...

Comment: I think many authors weaken the definition of commutativity in some special cases.